# Understanding truth values for logic w/ quantifiers

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

a) *Determine the truth value of the statement $∃y∀x¬V(x,y)$ where $V(x,y) = x+y=2xy$*

b) *Determine the truth value of the statement $∃yV(1,y)$ where $V(x,y) = x+y=2xy$*

My process for figuring out a) is to translate it into English as `There exists a value of y where all x values return false in V(x,y)`. I interpret this as there is a value of y that fits for an instance where x can be any number in $V(x,y)$ to make it false which is true from my understanding (say $x=1$; there are values of y that make $1+y=2y$ false.

For b), I again translate it into English: `There exists a value of y that returns true in V(1,y)`. To me, this means I should try to solve for a value of y, and if possible, then $V(x,y)$ is true since a given y-value fits.

Am I on the right track? My tentative answers are `True` and `True` for a) and b) respectively.

I am particularly new to math logic and I must admit math is not my area of strength. The textbook I am using is less than helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b) is certainly true because $V(1,1)$.

For a), you need to find a $y$ such that $\neg V(x,y)$ for all $x$. That is, does there exist $y$ such that $x+y\neq 2xy$ for all $x$? Suppose we fix $y$. Then
$$
x+y=2xy\iff y=x(2y-1)\iff x=\frac{y}{2y-1}.
$$
So for any $y$, there exists $x$ such that $V(x,y)$ ASSUMING THAT $\frac{y}{2y-1}$ is in your set for all $y$. So if all $\frac{y}{2y-1}$ exist in your set for whatever $y$, then a) is true. Otherwise, a) is false.

Comment: Just to clarify (this is immensely confusing): $∃y∀x$ means `for every value of x, there exists a y for V(x,y)`? Why is it not true, then?

Comment: To add to that (since it might've sounded confusing): in x + y = 2xy, for any given value of x, there exists a y where it is false. This means it is true, then, right?